# Multinomial logit with sample weighting in python or R

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, mlogit

I would like to run a multinomial logit estimate in python or R in which samples have different weights (these are population weights in a survey). `statsmodels`' `MNLogit` does not seem to provide this. Neither does `mlogit` in R. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Not available in statsmodels, but maybe just a few hours or days of work to add it.

Comment: Try `multinom()` in package `nnet`?

Comment: @sirallen: I don't see this option there, but if you want to suggest how, please...